# Wrong page in table of contents for my bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, page-numbering, page

The bibliography begins at page 35 but in the table of contents it begins one page before, at the same page as the conclusion.
How can I correct this error in the table of contents?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}

...

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}

% Bibliography
\RequirePackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\AtBeginDocument{
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}}

\begin{document}
   \input{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

%pagina vuota dopo titolo
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

   \input{Acknowledgement.tex}
   \input{Abstract.tex}
   \tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

   \input{introduction.tex}
   \input{Introduction accumulators.tex}
   \input{Design accumulators in key exchange protocols.tex}
   \input{Applications.tex}
   \input{Conclusion.tex}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

and in my file *biblio.bib*

```
\begin{thebibliography}

@inproceedings{benaloh1993one,
  title={One-way accumulators: A decentralized alternative to digital signatures},
  author={Benaloh, Josh and Mare, Michael de},
  booktitle={Workshop on the Theory and Application of of Cryptographic Techniques},
  pages={274--285},
  year={1993},
  organization={Springer}
}
...

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: table of contents]

[image: my bibliography]

Comment: \cleardoublepage \addcontentsline ....  (or use a package like tocinbib which handles that correctly).

Comment: The package is called `tocbibind` not `tocinbib`. The reason it fails is that here `\bibliography` writes a header as if it was using `\chapter*` thus it starts on a new page. So `\addcontentsline` and the actual text is on different pages. Ulrikes suggestion ensures they are in the same page. Here it is just easier to use `tocbibind`

Comment: I added \clearpage before \addcontentsline and it works! thank you all!

Comment: @daleif well I had nearly all letters right ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I had to check a few times as I was writing `tocbibin` in my comment.